# Index Out of Range Exception - Active Directory Adapter

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I understand what an Index Out of Range Exception is, however, I can't seem to figure out what is going on in the Stack Trace below.

This is an asp.net website, and it has been working without issue for the past few years.  I have checked with the System Administrator and they noted nothing has changed on the server hosting the website or dc.  Currently at a stand still, any ideas as to where to look or begin diagnosing?

```
[IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.]
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SidList.TranslateSids(String target, IntPtr[] pSids) +1507
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.SidList..ctor(SID_AND_ATTR[] sidAndAttr) +142
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.ADStoreCtx.GetGroupsMemberOfAZ(Principal p) +220
System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal.GetAuthorizationGroupsHelper() +50
PayDirectory.Classes.ActiveDirectoryAdapter.IsUserAllowed(String username, IList`1 allowedgroups) in C:\Users\johndoe\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\PayDirectory\PayDirectory\Classes\ActiveDirectoryAdapter.cs:35
PayDirectory.Controllers.AccountController.CheckUser(String sessionid) in C:\Users\johndoe\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\PayDirectory\PayDirectory\Controllers\AccountController.cs:42    
lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +108
System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +17
System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +188
System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +28
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +12
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
```

Etc.

That is the beginning of the Stack Trace, I can post the entire trace if necessary.

Basically, the application takes the session id of a user logged into Joomla, checks ad to see if that user is in a particular group (Principals) and allows them to view certain content, otherwise it will state Access is Denied.

**EDIT**
Adding source code for "IsuserAllowed" in ActiveDirectoryAdapter class

```
    public Boolean IsUserAllowed(string username, IList<string> allowedgroups)
    {
        PrincipalContext domain = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "Redmond");

        UserPrincipal user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domain, username);

        List<GroupPrincipal> groups = new List<GroupPrincipal>();

        if (user != null)
        {
            PrincipalSearchResult<Principal> authGroups = user.GetAuthorizationGroups();

            foreach (Principal p in authGroups)
            {
                if (p is GroupPrincipal)
                {
                    groups.Add((GroupPrincipal)p);
                }
            }
        }

        string groupstring = string.Join(",", (object[])groups.ToArray());
        string[] groupnames = groupstring.Split(',');

        for (int i = 0; i < allowedgroups.Count; i++)
        {
            if (groupnames.Contains(allowedgroups[i]))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: can you post the src of `PayDirectory.Classes.ActiveDirectoryAdapter.IsUserAllowed`?

Comment: @mxmissile Added the source code above in an Edit.

Comment: `PrincipalContext` implements `IDisposable`, so you should put it inside a `using` statement.

Comment: Hi @Amy Why would it need to be inside a using statement.  Could you give me a quick example and explanation?  Thanks!

Comment: Because it implements `IDisposable` like I said.  I assume you don't want memory leaks?  There are plenty of examples online.